# Twitter Login Giving Issue "JavaScript is Not Available"

Tags: android, kotlin, authentication, twitter

I have Integrated Twitter Authentication  to my android application.

Using the Twitter SDK kit

Recently facing a issue in login.
after entering the login credentials a screen is showed which says, "Javascript is not available".

Sharing a Screen Shot.

[image: Click to view the ScreenSHot]

```
implementation 'com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-core:3.1.1' 
implementation 'com.twitter.sdk.android:tweet-ui:3.1.1' 
implementation 'com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:3.0.0' 


private var twitterClient: TwitterAuthClient? = null 

private fun registerTwitterSDK() {
        twitterConfig =
            TwitterConfig.Builder(this).logger(DefaultLogger(Log.DEBUG)).twitterAuthConfig(
                TwitterAuthConfig(
                    getString(R.string.API_KEY), getString(R.string.SECRET_API_KEY)
                )
            ).debug(true).build()
        Twitter.initialize(twitterConfig)

        twitterClient = TwitterAuthClient()
    } 


 private fun loginWithTwitter() {

        twitterClient?.authorize(this, object : Callback<TwitterSession>() {
            override fun success(result: Result<TwitterSession>?) {
                fetchUserData(result)
            }

            override fun failure(exception: TwitterException?) {
                exception?.message?.let { toastMessage(it) }
            }
        })
    }

 private fun fetchUserData(twitterSession: Result<TwitterSession>?) {
        twitterClient?.requestEmail(getTwitterSession(), object : Callback<String>() {
            override fun success(emailData: Result<String>?) {
                //access token is id that we get from twitter
                callSocialLoginAPI(
                    emailData?.data.toString(),
                    twitterSession?.data?.id.toString(),
                    AppConstants.LOGIN_TYPE_SOCIAL
                )
            }

            override fun failure(exception: TwitterException?) {
                exception?.message?.let { toastMessage(it) }

            }
        })
    }

    private fun getTwitterSession(): TwitterSession {
        return TwitterCore.getInstance().sessionManager.activeSession
    }
```